# Table of averages by date for multiple IDs

Tags: ms-access, group-by, grouping, average

I have a table full of items that each have a unique `ItemID`.  There is another table with information on tests that are done on these items around once a month (some may have multiple tests per month and some may have none some months) and each test entry has a full date `mm/dd/yyyy`.  I would like to display the average of one of the fields over all the data on a monthly basis.  So assuming what I'm averaging is the item weight, I want to end up with a table like this:

```
Date AvgOfWeight  
1/09 24.55  
2/09 28.64  
3/09 22.39
```

and so on...

I know that I can do a query to do averages and I can group the averages by certain criteria, but is there an easy way to group `mm/dd/yyyy` dates by month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love this strzero function that can be used here this way:

```
m_monthYear = strZero(year(date()),4) & "-" & strZero(month(date()),2)
```

Results look like 2009-09 and can be ordered ascending, as they begin with the year. You'll just have to create this strZero function as follows:

```
Public function strZero(x_myLong as long, x_length as integer) as string
Dim m_strZero as string

m_strZero = trim(str(x_myLong))
do while len(m_strZero) <= x_length
    m_strZero = "0" & m_strZero
loop
strZero = m_strZero
end function
```

This was written on the fly. Please check all parameters (if any) for str, add error management, and adapt to your own needs. You might like to pass `x_myLong` as a variant, in order to return a '0000' string for example. This function has multiple other uses when converting numbers to fixed length strings.

Comment: This is basically what i ended up doing.  I did it all in SQL though.  I grouped by Year: Year(Date) and then by Month: Month(Date) and then for display purposes I made an expression Year_Date: CStr(Year) + "/" + CStr(Month).  THanks for the help